# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function jQM Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, autocomplete

I like to use jQ Mobile Autocomplete https://github.com/commadelimited/autoComplete.js. But when I copy the example of jQM from http://andymatthews.net/code/autocomplete/local_complex.html to local server i always get the error:  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function. Here is the code i tryed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jqm.autoComplete-1.5.2-min.js"></script>
<script src="code.js"></script>
```

```
<div data-role="page" id="mainPage">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>jQM Autocomplete</h1>
        <div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">

        <h3>Local Complex Data</h3>

        <p>
            In this example autoComplete returns an array of objects from a local variable, each with a label and a value key.
        </p>
    <p>
            <input type="text" id="searchField" placeholder="Categories">
            <ul id="suggestions" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
        </p>

        <p>
            <a href="https://github.com/commadelimited/autoComplete.js" data-role="button">Download the code</a>
        </p>

    </div>

</div>

<script>

    $("#mainPage").bind("pageshow", function(e) {

             autocompleteData = $.parseJSON('[{"value":"1.0","label":"Alabama"},{"value":"2.0","label":"Alaska"},{"value":"3.0","label":"American Samoa"},{"value":"4.0","label":"Arizona"},{"value":"5.0","label":"Arkansas"},{"value":"6.0","label":"California"},{"value":"7.0","label":"Colorado"},{"value":"8.0","label":"Connecticut"},{"value":"9.0","label":"Delaware"},{"value":"10.0","label":"District of Columbia"},{"value":"11.0","label":"Florida"},{"value":"12.0","label":"Georgia"},{"value":"13.0","label":"Guam"},{"value":"14.0","label":"Hawaii"},{"value":"15.0","label":"Idaho"},{"value":"16.0","label":"Illinois"},{"value":"17.0","label":"Indiana"},{"value":"18.0","label":"Iowa"},{"value":"19.0","label":"Kansas"},{"value":"20.0","label":"Kentucky"},     {"value":"21.0","label":"Louisiana"},  {"value":"22.0","label":"Maine"},{"value":"23.0","label":"Maryland"},{"value":"24.0","label":"Massachusetts"},{"value":"25.0","label":"Michigan"},{"value":"26.0","label":"Minnesota"},{"value":"27.0","label":"Mississippi"},{"value":"28.0","label":"Missouri"},{"value":"29.0","label":"Montana"},{"value":"30.0","label":"Nebraska"},{"value":"31.0","label":"Nevada"},{"value":"32.0","label":"New Hampshire"},{"value":"33.0","label":"New Jersey"},{"value":"34.0","label":"New Mexico"},{"value":"35.0","label":"New York"},{"value":"36.0","label":"North Carolina"},{"value":"37.0","label":"North Dakota"},{"value":"38.0","label":"Northern Marianas Islands"},{"value":"39.0","label":"Ohio"},{"value":"40.0","label":"Oklahoma"},{"value":"41.0","label":"Oregon"},{"value":"42.0","label":"Pennsylvania"},{"value":"43.0","label":"Puerto Rico"},{"value":"44.0","label":"Rhode Island"},{"value":"45.0","label":"South Carolina"},{"value":"46.0","label":"South Dakota"},{"value":"47.0","label":"Tennessee"},{"value":"48.0","label":"Texas"},{"value":"49.0","label":"Utah"},{"value":"50.0","label":"Vermont"},{"value":"52.0","label":"Virgin Islands"},{"value":"51.0","label":"Virginia"},{"value":"53.0","label":"Washington"},{"value":"54.0","label":"West Virginia"},{"value":"55.0","label":"Wisconsin"},{"value":"56.0","label":"Wyoming"}]');

        $("#searchField").autocomplete({
            target: $('#suggestions'),
            source: autocompleteData,
            link: 'target.html?term=',
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Did `jqm.autoComplete-1.5.2-min.js` load correctly? Is your `script` tags in `head` section?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The script wasn't load correctly. Yes the script tags are in head section.